# Loop through a dataframe and remove element one at a time by index value

Tags: python

is there a way to loop through a dataframe and remove element one at a time by index value that match values from another list.

```
pd.DataFrame(["apple", "john", "sam", "pols", "rock" ])


list1 = ["1", "3", "1","1"]
```

Based on the first value on the list, I want to delete the item in the dataframe that match the index value. The first element in the list above is 1 and I want to delete the dataframe item in index 1. After the first loop my dataframe should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "sam", "pols", "rock" ])


list1 = ["1", "3", "1", "1"]
```

After the second loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "sam", "pols"])


list1 = ["1", "3", "1", "1"]
```

After the third loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "pols"])


list1 = ["1", "3", "1", "1"]
```

And go down the line for each value in the list.

I tried to do this using the code below but I'm not getting the correct results.

```
for a in df.index:
    for b in list1:
        if a == b:
            drop.a
```

I'm new to python and any help or tips will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you could try df.drop(i) where i is the index

Comment: @ShreyaPandita when I try that, it returns the whole dataframe without any items removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
for i in list1:
        j=int(i)
        df.drop(df.index[j],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

And just to let you know, in your solution you were trying to iterate through and modify the dataframe at the same time. I suggest you to not do that with any datatype.